# div doesn't respond when clicking on it in a show more/less container

Tags: javascript, dom

So this div doesn't respond when I click on the h3 inside it or on the span
I used flex box in the "question-title" div, I guess that what causes the problem, is there a way I can make this div showing more/less when I click on it, not specifically outside h3 and the span, because it only works when I click in the space between h3 and the span.

```js
let downBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".main-question .question-title");

downBtn.forEach(dbtn => {

    dbtn.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {

        let paragraphElement = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("p");

        paragraphElement.classList.toggle("showHide");

        let spanSign = dbtn.querySelector("span");

        if (paragraphElement.classList.contains("showHide")) {
            spanSign.innerHTML = "--";
        } else {
            spanSign.innerHTML = "+";
        }

    });

});
```

```css
.question {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.part-one h3 {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.main-question {
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(207, 207, 207);
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-question h4 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #607d8b;
}
.main-question h4::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.main-question p {
    margin: 34px 0 0;
    text-align: justify;
    color: var(--main-color2);
    display: none;
}
.main-question p.showHide {
    display: block;
}
.question-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 20px;
}
.question-title span {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #607d8b;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}
.question-title span::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start questions -->
  <div class="container">
      <div class="question">
         <div class="part-one">
          <h3>Some Frequent Questions</h3>
          <div class="main-question">
              <div class="question-title">
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
              <span>+</span>
              </div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorum fugiat ullam molestias dignissimos deleniti inventore aspernatur nam excepturi vitae nihil, temporibus accusantium tempore deserunt error libero, itaque earum sapiente sequi.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="main-question">
              <div class="question-title">
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
              <span>+</span>
              </div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorum fugiat ullam molestias dignissimos deleniti inventore aspernatur nam excepturi vitae nihil, temporibus accusantium tempore deserunt error libero, itaque earum sapiente sequi.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="main-question">
              <div class="question-title">
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</h4>
              <span>+</span>
              </div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorum fugiat ullam molestias dignissimos deleniti inventore aspernatur nam excepturi vitae nihil, temporibus accusantium tempore deserunt error libero, itaque earum sapiente sequi.</p>
          </div>
         </div>

      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End questions -->
```

Comment: I think your CSS causes the problem, because JS looks good. Did you check if showHide class toggled?

Comment: @Bülent Akgül Yes I did, JS works fine but only when I click on the space between h3 and span who are contained in the "question-title" div

Comment: That's normal because titles are listening to click event. Show your showHide styles.

Comment: @Bülent Akgül So the div listens to the click event and what inside it doesn't?...showHide class only gives display block to the paragraph inside the "main-question" div

Comment: See my answer down below.

Comment: @Bülent Akgül one last question. I added a transition to the showHide class so that we get a smooth effect but it doen't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is this line of code:

```
let paragraphElement = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("p");
```

Since you didn't set the indentations on your HTML properly, I didn't notice this issue in the first place.

You need to use this instead:

```
let paragraphElement = e.target.closest(".main-question").querySelector("p")
```

The answer of your question in the comment is NO, but when you click h4, you also click div because they are occupying the same area, unless you added stopPropagation to your function. But "e.target" is the item you clicked directly. If it's h4, its parentNode is "question-title" and it has no "p" child.

When you work with JS, always use console.log(). You can see the problem most of the time.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem. But can you please explain to me why using this.ParentNode.querySelector("p") didn't select the "p" tag in the "main-question" div.

Comment: I've explained it already. It didn't work because of how event.target works. Use console.log(e.target, e.target.parentNode) and click the text and empty space. You will see the difference.

Comment: Yes I got it...I thought when I click on the h3 then parent node will be same as the parent node for the div containing the h3 but console.log helped me understanding my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 0):

//This part is not necessary because the class "showHide" will be toggled below
<s>document.querySelectorAll(".main-question").forEach(el ...</s>

Also change your CSS for ".question-title" => "justify-content: space-around;" to show the icon

```
let downBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".main-question .question-title");
    
downBtn.forEach(dbtn => {

  dbtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  
    let paragraphElement = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("p");
    
    paragraphElement.classList.toggle("showHide");

    let spanSign = dbtn.querySelector("span");
    if (paragraphElement.classList.contains("showHide")) {
      spanSign.innerHTML = "--";
    } else {
      spanSign.innerHTML = "+";
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you. But why two parentNodes to select the p tag inside the "main-question" div, isn't one enough? cuz the question-title parentNode is the main-question which has a paragraph child

Comment: I logged it in the console and I found that e.target.parentElement gives me the same div we are clicking on, why?

Comment: Guess I got it, two parentNodes because we are clicking on the h3 and the span. Thank you again

Comment: but the paragraphElement  variable now only selects one main-question div, which is the first one in our html code

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. Next time when an error came up. Try to debug every (steps or lines or for loops -> console print each element) to make sure the correct target/element is selected. Hope this suggestion helps you in future debugging!